# ReactiveMongoTemplate-longer response time with spring boot 3.0

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

After upgrade of spring boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive I see that time the following method increased. Could you give me any clue why is that?
Old versions:
spring boot:2.7.10
spring-data-mongodb: 3.4.10
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive: 2.7.10
New versions:
spring boot:3.1.3
spring-data-mongodb: 4.1.2
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive: 3.1.3

```
  val result: Flux<Document> = reactiveMongoTemplate.find(query, Document::class.java, "collectionName")
```

Times in old version:
[image]

Times in new version:
[image]